# Seleccionar únicamente filas con una celda distinta

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatables

tengo la siguiente tabla (simplificada):

```
ID_CLIENTE  NOMBRE  TELEFONO    EDAD    ESTATURA     
1           MANOLO  987456321   56      1.80         
1           MANOLO  NULL        56      1.79         
2           LUCÍA   NULL        56      1.50         
2           LUCÍA   987456321   56      1.50
```

Y el resultado que espero es selecionar únicamente las celdas cuyo valor entre sí son distintas, es decir espero el resultado :

```
ID_CLIENTE  NOMBRE  TELEFONO    EDAD    ESTATURA     
1           -       987456321   -       1.80         
1           -       NULL        -       1.79         
2           -       NULL        -       -        
2           -       987456321   -       -
```

He probado utilizar un join con la propia tabla, pero el resultado se queda anidado y no en distintas filas. Presiento que se debe utilizar algún tipo de unión o intersección, ya que el resultado más similar al que se me pide lo he conseguido con el uso de UNION:

```
SELECT   '-' AS NOMBRE , TELEFONO , 0,
  FROM [test_temp].[dbo].[CLIENTE3]   

  UNION 

   SELECT  '-' AS NOMBRE , 0 AS TELEFONO, ESTATURA
  FROM [test_temp].[dbo].[CLIENTE3]
```

Pero los resultados son muchas veces incompletos o con duplicados:

```
NOMBRE  TELEFONO    (No column name)
-   NULL    0.00
-   0   1.45
-   0   1.50
-   0   1.56
-   0   1.70
-   0   1.74
-   0   1.80
-   0   1.90
-   0   1.96
-   987456321   0.00
```

Un saludo

Comment: El escenario está bastante incompleto. ¿Como se puede determinar el orden de las filas del idCliente?.  Para esto puedes hacer una cte con las funciones de ventana Lead o Lag y en base a lo que te devuelva el siguiente resultado, en la salida de la cte con un case, puedes o no mostrar un valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
    s1.ID_CLIENTE  as ID_CLIENT,
    case
        when exists (
            Select
                1
            from
                [test_temp].[dbo].[CLIENTE3] s2
            where
                s2.NOMBRE  = s1.NOMBRE 
                and s2.ID_CLIENTE  <> s1.ID_CLIENTE  
        ) then '-'
        else s1.NOMBRE 
    end as NOMBRE ,
    --Para cada caso de cada columna
from
    [test_temp].[dbo].[CLIENTE3] s1
```

Aquí la columana nombre se verifica en busca de duplicados y, si se encuentra, se reemplaza con -. Para cada columna con esta regla de duplicados, hay que repetir este caso (cambiando el nombre a la columna respectiva).